# Brillouin Zones as diffraction zones for a crystal lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, solid-mechanics

Diffractions usually occur when planar waves strike a gap that has less than or equal to the size of the wavelength. Is it correct to assume that Brillouin zones are the gaps in the crystal lattice that acts like the gap in the atom for diffraction to occur?

Answer (score 0):

The brillouin zone is the set of allowable wavevectors that are unique modulo the set of reciprocal lattice vectors $\{\vec{K_i}\}$.

Waves on a lattice with wavevector, $\vec{k}$, are physically indistinguishable from the set of wavevectors, $\{\vec{w} \}\equiv \vec{k} + \{\vec{K_i}\}$.

We define the first brillouin zone as the set of unique wave vectors nearest to the origin.

If we denote first brillouin zone as $\{H\}$, then we can tile the space like $\{H\} + \{\vec{K_i}\}$.